# WSO2IS With Custom Context Root

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-identity-server

My team is trying to expose WSO2-IS through a reverse proxy. With our team setup, each new application is exposed under a single context-root, and we're hoping to do the same for wso2.

Using the oauth2/authorize endpoint as an example, we would like to expose the endpoint through our proxy as

- `https://<domain name>/wso2-is/oauth2/authorize` rather than the default
- `https://<domain name>/oauth2/authorize`

It turns out we would need this same configuration for a number of webapps under wso2is, including:

- oauth2
- oidc
- commonauth
- logincontext
- authorizationendpoint

I've found information online for how to do this with the admin console, but I haven't found any info on how to do it for these public endpoints.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this, or does someone know whether or not WSO2 was built to support this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the official documentation on [Adding a Custom Proxy Path](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path).

**Update**
Related question [Configuring WSO2 IS behind a reverse proxy at some context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237634/configuring-wso2-is-behind-a-reverse-proxy-at-some-context)